# STFT zeropadding

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, dft, window-functions, stft

I am trying to implement the STFT by MATLAB, and I read somewhere that we must do zeropadding to the subsequence of the signal before windowing it with a Gaussian window. What happens if we don't do any windowing?

Comment: I think it's the same reason as why you'd want to Zero pad any signal before taking its FFT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't HAVE to zero pad, ever, unless there are constraints on the length of data required by the FFT algorithm - often it's a case of speed.

Many FFT's (like the Numerical Recipes code) require a power-of-two length series, some (like Kiss-FFT) only require it to be an even number, but being a multiple of 2,3 and 5 makes it run much faster.

In Matlab's case the algorithm is optimized for dealing with power-of-two length data. It usually pads the data to achieve this for you, though you control how many powers-of-two you wish to pad up to.